# Java Https - HttpsURLConnection - Unsupported SSLv2Hello

Tags: java

Ao fazer um pedido https tenho a seguinte exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version SSLv2Hello

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("URL");

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getResponseCode();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    }
```

A exception acontece no

> } catch (IOException e) {

ao tentar fazer

> conn.getResponseCode();

Comment: O problema é do certificado, o código está bem como disse. Obrigado pelo teste. Testei novamente com um https diferente e funcionou. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente está rodando este código em *runtime* da versão 8 do Java. `SSLv2` está [obsoleto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_2.0) já há um bom tempo, então não é mais suportado por padrão no *runtime* da versão 8, não tendo um *socket factory* para tal.

Você tem algumas opções neste cenário:

- fazer *downgrade* para um *runtime* da versão 7;
- forçar o uso de SSLv3 recuperando um contexto `TLSv1` que usa `SSLv3`. Um exemplo seria este:

```java
final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

final SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
ctx.init(null, null, null);
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
```

Você pode fazer globalmente também, usando isto:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```

Uma observação é: aqui está dando o erro `No name matching app.xxx.net found`, que é quando a informação do certificado do servidor é diferente do *host* no qual está tentando conectar. Em seu ambiente você poderá precisar configurar um [`HostnameVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html). [Esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093112/certificateexception-no-name-matching-ssl-someurl-de-found) resposta trata disto.

Testei em outro servidor HTTPS e está OK, a apenas este apresentou problema.